# Get exact postion of UIButton in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to animate the image of a UIButton, that is located in my UITableViewCell's, for this I need to get the exact currently position  of this button, how would I manage to get this?

This is my code, but when the animation starts from the same location everytime, eventhough it should start from the UIButton in the UITableViewCell.

```
    - (void)addToCartTapped:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // grab the cell using indexpath
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *btnImage; 
     for (UIButton *btn in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
        {
            if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
            {
               btnImage = [btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }    

    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImage]; 

    CGRect rect = [imgV.superview convertRect:imgV.frame fromView:nil];
    rect = CGRectMake(5, (rect.origin.y*-1)-10, imgV.frame.size.width, imgV.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"rect is %f,%f,%f,%f",rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);

    // create new duplicate image
    UIImageView *starView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgV.image];
    [starView setFrame:rect];
    starView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    starView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    starView.layer.borderWidth=1;
    [self.view addSubview:starView];

    // begin ---- apply position animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    pathAnimation.duration=0.65;
    pathAnimation.delegate=self;

    // tab-bar right side item frame-point = end point
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(210+rect.size.width/2, 390+rect.size.height/2);

    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, starView.frame.origin.x, starView.frame.origin.y);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, starView.frame.origin.y, endPoint.x, starView.frame.origin.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
    // end ---- apply position animation

    // apply transform animation
    CABasicAnimation *basic=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    [basic setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)]];
    [basic setAutoreverses:NO];
    [basic setDuration:0.65];

    [starView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curveAnimation"];
    [starView.layer addAnimation:basic forKey:@"transform"];

    [starView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.65];
    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadBadgeNumber) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.65];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add code below to get button frame in nslog

```
- (void)addToCartTapped:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // grab the cell using indexpath
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *btnImage; 
    CGRect btnImage_rect;
    for (UIButton *btn in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
        {
            if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
            {
               btnImage =[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
               btnImage_rect.frame=btn.frame;
               NSLog(@"rect is %@", btnImage_rect);
            }
        }

   //added your own code here .after you will get button frame    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add a button a UITableViewCell then when you get attempt to get it's position by doing something like:

```
 button.position.x;
```

it may be it's position within the UITableViewCell and not globally.

Comment: iOS SDK does not contain this syntax.